# How to handle the pop window to access the pop elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having testcase for handle the popup but control is not going to popup window. It is displaying the getTitle of main window instead of popup window. can you go through below code.

```
@Test
public void testText1() throws Exception {
    driver.get("http://www.hdfcbank.com");
    Thread.sleep(8000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginsubmit']")).click();

    String popupHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    WebDriver popup;

    popup = driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
    System.out.println(popup.getTitle());
    if (popup.getTitle().equals("netbanking")) {
        System.out.println("I am going to access the elements of popup");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[6]/a/img")).click();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Worth Trying try harder to get success");
        //   
    }

}
```

Output:
                {d0f39d30-49e7-4203-b9ef-10380fbfcb5e}
               HDFC Bank: Personal Banking Services
             I am going to access the elements of popup
              Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable             to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[6]/a/img"}
              Command duration or timeout: 30.15 seconds

Comment: Hi @Satendra what do you mean by pop up window? Is it java script window or html pop up? If it is html pop up then you don't have to follow the method you have created. It is straight forward process. Let me know if you require more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.  The `driver.getWindowHandle()` method returns only the handle for the current window, which would be your main window.  If another pop-up window opens, you will need to call `Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles()` to return a list of all available handles.  Then you can call `driver.switchTo().window(handles.get(handles.size() - 1))`.  This will switch to the last listed (newest) window handle.

You also don't need to declare a new WebDriver object.  By calling `switchTo()`, you are transferring the driver's focus to the new window.  Make sure to save a reference to the main window's handle before making the switch so that you will be able to switch back to the main window afterwards.

```
String mainHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
String[] handles = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray(new String[0]);
driver.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]);
...
driver.close(); //close the popup window
driver.switchTo().window(mainHandle);
```

Comment: handles.get(handles.size() - 1) it is displaying compiler error. it is required digit value

Comment: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method get(int)
  location: variable handles of type java.util.Set<java.lang.String>
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)

Comment: Sorry about that, I revised the example code to convert to an array first, so the last item can be retrieved.